# Trying to create a rolling row limit stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Platform: SQL Server

**Goal**: get the current number of rows and subtract from it the amount I want to keep and then delete the remainder. I was planning to turn it into a stored procedure if I could get it working.

For the code I was thinking something like this:

```
SET N = (EXEC sp_spaceused dbo.Name rows)
SET  D = (%N%-30000000)

DELETE TOP (%D%) FROM dbo.Name
```

I used `sp_spaceused` to avoid locking the table to input statements, as would be the case with count.

Comment: @squillman Updatable CTE or view works fine with just `TOP` you don;'t need `WHERE` or `JOIN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an updatable CTE or derived table to delete. Assuming you wanted to delete random rows from the table, you don't need any further calculations.

Don't use `sp_spaceused`, get the data from `sys.partitions` instead

```sql
DECLARE @N int = (
  SELECT SUM(p.rows)
  FROM sys.partitions p
  INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
  WHERE t.name = N'Name'
    AND s.name = N'dbo'
    AND p.index_id IN (0,1)
);

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TOP (@N - 30000000)
      *
    FROM dbo.Name
)
DELETE FROM cte;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5661ff6ead7096e55f4fbf2b716bcfd7)

Comment: Hadn't thought of this, good call